# How to set PopupWindow at bottom of root layout like soft keyboard?

Tags: java, android, android-keypad, android-popupwindow

whenever focus is available on edittext.
Keyboard is open and all views are adjust and go upward like below sample image.

[image]

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                FileUtils.hideKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout,null);

                DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
                int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
                int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
                popupWindow = new PopupWindow(customView, width, 300);
                //display the popup window
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(rootlayout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
            }
        });
```

This code is working fine but popup is showing bottom of screen and it stay on rootlayout.
I want this popup is open and stay like keyboard with animation .

Answer (score 0):

You can use bottom dialog for this

`BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(YourActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(YourView);
dialog.show();`

Comment: it also open like popup window . It is not showing like keyboard